# Numpy array creation without broadcasting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

```
one = np.array([[1], [0]])
```

How `arr` can be created such that, every element of `arr` would be equal to `one`?

If I do:

```
arr = one * 4
```

Due to broadcasting above statement doesn't give the desired behavior.

Comment: What's the shape of `arr` supposed to be?   With  lists `* 4` is a replication, but with arrays it is plain numeric multiplication.

Comment: @hpaulj I accepted the answer, it does exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `repeat`:

```
np.repeat(one[np.newaxis, ...], 4, axis=0)
```

Alternatively, you can try `broadcast_to`. This will be faster but read-only:

```
np.broadcast_to(one, (4, *one.shape))
```